# Cleaning mysql field of hidden characters

Tags: mysql, special-characters

I have a MySQL table of country codes, country names, and thier geographic realms. I did this using a LOAD DATA INFILE... and i think their is some special characters. When I execute the statement

```
Select * from countrylist where country_realm!='Africa'
```

I still get many Africa. On top of that if i do a group by, i get 2 sets of africa. I have tried all the cleansing technics found here: [Remove special characters from a database field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066953/remove-special-characters-from-a-database-field)

But it still doesnt work.

Also if I execute the statement

```
Select * from countrylist where country_realm NOT LIKE '%Africa%'
```

It works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `TRIM`?

```
UPDATE countrylist SET country_realm = TRIM(country_realm);
```