# Remove characters from specific field on tables

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to clean up a database where one of the columns (TOTAL_AREA) has some characters on some of the entries (not all of them)

Such as 5000㎡

I need to clean all the fields that have this entry to show only 500

How can I do it with SQL? I looked at TRIM but couldn't find a way to select all entries that have a character after the number and them TRIM it

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066953/remove-special-characters-from-a-database-field

Comment: Are you sure you want to return 500 and not 5,000?

Comment: Btw, your tags are confusing - is it MySQL or Snowflake ?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy.  MySQL does implicit conversion, ignoring characters after the digits.  So, you can do:

```
select (col * 1.0 / 10)
```

For your example, this will return 500.

Comment: in my case, when I run it, it comes back with this message: Numeric value '5000㎡以上' is not recognized

Comment: @tokyodev . . . Really?  This works fine when I try it and on SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/55554).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to get rid of all characters that are not digits, you can use e.g. [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace.html), e.g.

```
create or replace table x(s string);

insert into x values
  ('111'),
  ('abc234xyz'),
  ('5000㎡'),
  ('9000㎡以上');

select s, regexp_replace(s, '[^\\d]*(\\d+)[^\\d]*', '\\1') from x;
-----------+--------------------------------------------------+
     S     | REGEXP_REPLACE(S, '[^\\D]*(\\D+)[^\\D]*', '\\1') |
-----------+--------------------------------------------------+
 111       | 111                                              |
 abc234xyz | 234                                              |
 5000㎡     | 5000                                             |
 9000㎡以上   | 9000                                             |
-----------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

What we do there is we match sequences of 0-or-more non-digit characters, followed by 1-or-more digit characters, and again 0-or-more non-digit characters, and product only the middle sequence.

Note, that you can use a different regexp depending what characters exactly you want to keep/remove.