# Replace Escaped Apostrophe in SQL File with Python

Tags: python, sql, escaping, apostrophe

I am cleaning up a SQL script to replace escaped apostrophes \' with '' as it is in MySQL syntax and I need it to work in MSSQL but no matter what I try it doesn't work. How do you replace escaped apostrophes with two apostrophes in a file with Python?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out replace("\'", "''") works. I'm sure I tried this but it must have been something else that stopped it from working initially.

Answer (score 0):

Create a store procedure the write the script to replace the special characters or regular expression like

`update table set column = REPLACE(column,"'",'"');
update table set column = REPLACE(column,"/","");

update table set column = REPLACE(column,"'",""");`

Reference : [Remove special characters from a database field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066953/remove-special-characters-from-a-database-field)

And in the last call it by using Python script

> EXEC PROC procedureName

Comment: Thanks, but it's the actual SQL insert statement itself that needs the escaped apostrophe replaced with '', so I can actually run it to begin with.